# show content of token register as a string in the document

Tags: luatex, verbatim

I'm trying to implement a command that can execute its argument, but also print it.

To that end I'm dumping the argument into a toks register and use LuaTex to put it back with inactive catcodes; as it says in the manual:

> `tex.print(<number> n, <string> s, ...)`
>   If n is −1, the currently active catcode regime is used. If n is −2,
>   the resulting catcodes are the result of \the\toks: all category codes
>   are 12 (other) except for the space character, that has category code
>   10 (space)

```
\newcommand{\showandtell}[1]{\toks0{#1}%
   {using the argument #1 executes}\\
   {printing with current
      \directlua{tex.print(-1, tex.toks[0])} executes}\\
   {printing with inert \texttt{
      \directlua{tex.print(-2, tex.toks[0])}} shows the code}\\
   {reading the register \the\toks0 executes}
}
\noindent\showandtell{\bfseries\color{red}}
```

From "the resulting catcodes are the result of \the\toks" in the manual I was expecting `\the\toks0` to have the opposite effect.

How can I get the effect of `print(-2` in pure TeX?

The token register appears to be stored as a string, discarding the original catcodes, but then how can packages like verbatim just use just `\the\verbatim@line` and produce plain output?

[image: output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can obtain the same effect in e-TeX (not in Knuth TeX) with `\detokenize`, which is available when LaTeX is used (on TeX distributions not more than ten years old).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\showandtell}[1]{%
  {using the argument #1 executes}\\%
  printing with detokenize \texttt{\detokenize{#1}} shows the code%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\showandtell{\bfseries\color{red}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use a token register, then `\detokenize\expandafter{\the\toks0}` will do.

Verbatim modes attain their purpose by changing category codes before starting to read the material, which is why they can't be used in the argument to a command. Note, however, that `\detokenize`, like the LuaTeX code you used, adds a space after control words (which verbatim modes don't).

Comment: by "plain tex" I just meant "not using Lua" here, so that works for me. I was confused by the apparent use of character strings for the register, but "token registers accept and return Lua strings. Lua strings are converted to and from token lists" (so I guess the original catcode will be part of the token which is invisible in the string)

Answer (score 7):

It is also possible to achieve this in Knuth TeX via `\meaning`. Although there is no reason not to use `\detokenize` if it is available.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\let\StripPrefix\strip@prefix % Latex kernel command
\makeatother

\newcommand{\showandtell}[1]{%
  {using the argument #1 executes}\\%
  \def\TEMP {#1}%
  playing tricks with meaning \texttt{\expandafter\StripPrefix\meaning\TEMP} shows the code%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\showandtell{\bfseries\color{red}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

and if you want to show things from `\toks0` register you can do

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\TEMP\expandafter{\the\toks0}
```

or simpler

```
\edef\TEMP{\the\toks0}
```

and then the `\meaning` thing.